# Why do I give my pets "food" but my livestock "feed"?

Tags: etymology, animals

When I feed my cat or my dog, the package tends to say "Dog Food" or "Cat Food."

In contrast, I give my chickens "chicken feed" or "poultry feed."  Likewise, a cow's silage is her "feed."

Why does this distinction exist?  Is there an historical or grammatical explanation, or is it merely idiom?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Germanic languages like English inherit a distinction between eating (of people) and eating (of animals). German has two verbs, *essen* and *fressen*, that make precisely this distinction. To say that *Er frisst es* instead of *Er isst es* 'He eats it' is an insult, implying he's eating like an animal.

English has lost the special verb, but has adapted the causative *feed* 'cause to eat, provide nourishment' to work with both senses, and its Zero-suffix nominalization *feed* to refer to food intended for animals. It appears in several fixed phrases: a *Seed and Feed store* sells food for animals plus seeds and gardening stuff; if you are *off your feed* then you have little appetite and are behaving like a sick animal; *a good feed* is a banquet where everyone eats too much.

And as The English Chicken has pointed out, pets are honorary humans and they get treated like humans in our language, with pronouns like *he* and *she* (**never** *it*), and this is just another reflection of that fact.

Comment: Und warum habe ich nicht daruber gedacht? Naturlich! Danke!

Comment: The first paragraph, however interesting, is not directly related to the distinction between *feed* and *food* you described in your second paragraph.
And although the honorary human status of pets may play a role in the distinction, it cannot be really proven, and it may just as well be that *feed* is a professional jargon, which is not in use in households.

Comment: Feed is called feed because you use it for *feeding*.

Comment: I think the answer is wrong. Pets do not have a special "honorary human" status. The reason pets are referred to by he/she rather than it because they generally have names. In English things with names are he/she, not it, like ships.

Comment: One might as easily argue that the awarding of names and pronouns to pets is yet another mark of their anthropomorphological status. Which came first, the names or the need for names?

Answer (score 22):

Generally, *feed* is what you give to animals, while *food* is for people. Pets like cats and dogs enjoy an elevated status as human companions, so their meals are also called *food*, unlike those of the more impersonal livestock on a farm (Hence chickens have to contend with *feed* ... sigh).

Comment: I'd have though *tropical fish* come even lower down the "pecking order" than chickens. Not that I keep either, so maybe I'm not qualified to pontificate. But written instances of [tropical fish food](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tropical+fish+feed%2Ctropical+fish+food&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) massively outweigh *"feed"*.

Comment: But fish are still pets, whereas chickens and cows are traditionally domesticated for their use on the farm.

Comment: Grammar has a whole lot more to do with affective than with logical connections. Anybody can empathize with a cute mammal, but reptiles and fish, while pets, require more concentration and display fewer recognizable anthropomorphic traits.

Answer (score 9):

*Food* is the older of the two words, with *feed* coming into use as food for cattle only in the sixteenth century. The OED’s definition of *food*  is ‘Any nutritious substance that people **or animals** eat or drink’ (my emphasis) and, as The English Chicken has mentioned, we still speak of *dog food* and *cat food*. Conversely, *feed* can be that which is consumed by humans, if only colloquially. One OED citation has ‘The cook is French and feed delicious’ and, another, in a rather different sense, ‘Little boys . . . having a feed of ice-cream.’