# Right verb for 'pass'

Tags: verbs

I've a function that takes one or more arguments and I want to say the way to pass parameters.
For instance: you can pass (maybe give?) a number and a string to that function.

What is the right verb to say what I want to say?

Thanks in advance!

Wilk

Comment: Who is your audience? What is their skill level and do they understand the jargon in your field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technical term for passing (as you yourself said) arguments to a function is indeed pass, i.e.

> You can pass a number and a string to that function.

Another less technical, but still understood, term would be *to feed*

> You can feed a number and a string to that function.

Yet another more generic (i.e. not related to programming) alternative would be *to provide*

> You can provide this function with a string and a number (as arguments).

Comment: If - as I infer from your question - your audience may not understand the term *to pass* in this context, then I would question whether they would understand *argument*, *function*, *string*, etc.. So either you assume they understand the jargon and use all the normal terminology, or you assume they do **not** understand the jargon and avoid using it at all.use

Comment: @TrevorD: Why would you be discussing a function with someone who doesn't know anything about programming at all? If it's a client, you shouldn't talk to them so low-level anyway, you just tell them that it's gonna look cute and that's it :)

Comment: My point exactly! So why is he asking what word to use when he already knows the jargon? And why are you suggesting using non-jargon terms such as *feed* and *provide*?

Comment: @TrevorD: I asked it because I'm italian and I wasn't sure if I was right or not with that term and I'm happy to know other ways to say what I meant in other contexts. So, thank you Armen ;)

Comment: @Wilk OK. But that wasn't apparent to me from your question. It appeared to me - especially as your English seems very good -  that you knew the jargon but wanted a corresponding **non-jargon** word. Hence my comments.

Comment: Three different metaphor themes here (all computer terms are [metaphors](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/April05Eye.pdf), because where else could they come from?): (1) _Pass_ is part of a Transfer metaphor X -> Y -> Z (X _passes_ Y _to_ Z). (2) _[Feed](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/54275/15299)_ is a specialized transfer metaphor -- transferring food for consumption by the recipient (NB: this metaphor is not usually extended to a program's output, only its input). (3) And _provide_ presupposes a need, which is an animate phenomenon (you can't _provide_ something that isn't needed).

Comment: So you could use "provide" in this context if the parameters are required as the function needs them.